# echo a link based on selected object in a form BEFORE submitting the form

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm fetching an array of data from a database to create a `select` element, but I can't get the page to echo a link based on the selected option I have.

Code to output the `select` box:

```
$options1 = json_decode($row['options'], true);
echo "<select name='" . $row['name'] . "'>";

foreach($options1 as $key => $location)//foreach loop  
{  
  echo "<option value='" . $location['org'] . "' selected='selected'>" . $location['org'] . "</option><br />";
}

echo "</select>";
```

I want it to echo out `$location['address'];` once an option is selected(NOT SUBMITTED).

The format of the array before using json_decode is;

```
[ {"org":"Org Name","address":"Address of org"}, {"org":"Org Name","address":"Address of org"},  {"org":"Org Name","address":"Address of org"}, {"org":"Org Name","address":"Address of org"}, {"org":"Org Name","address":"Address of org"}, {"org":"Org Name","address":"Address of org"}]
```

Comment: Show us your javascript/jquery code so far.

Comment: @Gerry removed it all out of annoyance lol. Still attempting a load of different methods and can't seem to work it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As stated by @Dave-S you need to built an array. As I don't know what it looks like, it's not included in the example, you just have commented lines in the script about it...*

**EDIT** : after array has been given, here's a quick fix:

You can use [jQuery .change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) -> *bind an event handler to the "change" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.* **and** [jQuery.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) -> *takes a well-formed JSON string and returns the resulting JavaScript value*.

> jQuery (used v. 3.2.1)

```
$(document).ready( function() {

var addresses = '[ {"org":"Org Name 1","address":"Address of org 1"}, {"org":"Org Name 2","address":"Address of org 2"}, {"org":"Org Name 3","address":"Address of org 3"} ]';

$("#changeit").change(function (){ // we use the function 'on change'

  $('select#changeit option:selected').each(function() { // the select
    selectedval = $(this).val(); // we catch the value of the selected option

    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(addresses); // we parse the array (see link to DOC)
    var address = obj[selectedval-1].address; // we access the data
    // note that 'selectedval' is minus 1 as array start with 0

    $('#output').html(address); // we print it in the div
    });

  });
});
```

> HTML

```
  <select class="form-select" id="changeit" name="changeit">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>

<p>Selected: <span id="output" name="output"></span></p>
```

Comment: [
   {"org":"Org Name","address":"Address of org"},
   {"org":"Org Name","address":"Address of org"},
   {"org":"Org Name","address":"Address of org"},
   {"org":"Org Name","address":"Address of org"},
   {"org":"Org Name","address":"Address of org"},
   {"org":"Org Name","address":"Address of org"}
] is the format before I use json_decode.

Comment: it doesn't seem to output anything after fixing it to suit what I have. I also tested the above on JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/kv85fbyr/1/

Comment: included jQuery and it works with my code, see it [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kv85fbyr/8/)

Comment: Edit: Never mind, it's something I've messed up on my end, fixed it on jsfiddle.

Comment: so it's ok I guess ?

Comment: It works when I manually enter in the array but when pulling it from the database it doesn't seem to work. However, when I pull it from the database and print, it outputs exactly how it shows when manually entering it. FULL Section of code: https://pastebin.com/rALLrhrw

Comment: `$location['org']` -> is that an integer, an ID ? the select uses numbers as values. And `var addresses = "' . $row['options'] . '";`  will most probably *not* be an array. Should `$options1` be the array ?

Comment: No it's not an integer, it's a string, didn't realize select MUST use numbers as values, I've just fixed that.  `$row['options']` outputs the array I given earlier on, `$options1` is just the `json_decode` part of the array.

Comment: So make sûre also that there is not a error php side (print the array and the decoded one to see if they exist) and it should work

Comment: Hm, printed both out and don't seem to have any issues from what I can see. https://pastebin.com/fn0MJ6X5

Comment: What is the final code you use then ? Did you make sure there is no problem with the json data as stated in the doc ? No special character or line breaker or whatsoever ?

Comment: The final code is; https://pastebin.com/aE5t7Yud I just triple checked the json data to ensure there's no issues and it seems to be fine. This has been baffling me for the last few hours lol.

Comment: Try split and separate php from HTML and JS and check console too if you see any error, as there should be...

Comment: So it's an issue with how it's pulling from the database I know where the issue is now. I appreciate the help! Thank you so much.

Comment: Well you know now :) something in the array is causing this, most likely an unauthorized character terminating it... at least you have made a couple of steps forward, should be easier to debug now (I have no time to look at it right now, be back later, hope this has helped though ^^)

Comment: Thanks for UV too, just saw it ;) happy coding

Comment: No problem! I appreciate the help a lot! Been driving me crazy lol. Back to finishing the system :D

Answer (score 0):

Build an array of (org > address) as a global Javascript variable in the page's HTML when first processing the database lookup.

Have a Javascript function called by on select to re-write the innerhtml of the div/span where the address is displayed.

No code here since this is a homework assignment.

Comment: I respect that lol. Already had the logic down for this and have the array in JS form, just unable to have it appear based on the selection. I do however have it so it outputs the selected text.